# Can someone help explain this example API call

Tags: java, android, rest, api, retrofit

So long story short, I am creating a java application for android and i need to access the USDA's "food data central" api. It is a REST api and I am using Retrofit to make my calls to the API. I am trying to figure out their example call to their API in the documentation but I am very new to this API stuff so I am a little lost.

They have this listed as their "Example Call"

> curl -H "Content-Type:application/json"
>
> -X POST
>
> -d '{"generalSearchInput":"Cheddar cheese"}'
>
> https://DEMO_KEY@api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/search

I know the -X means it is a post command to the API and I believe the -d contains the request parameters but I am completely lost as to what the first line means. Also do you think the last line is the header? or the header and the endpoint.  Thank you so much for looking.

Here is the link to the [documentation page](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/api-guide.html#food-detail-endpoint)

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a http call being made by a tool called curl. It's just a way to make http requests via the command line. The last line is the endpoint.

Here are a few resources to get you started with curl:

- The doc page for curl: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html
- Curl explained in video format: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XUibDYw4mc

Answer (score 0):

The first line sets the header `Content-Type` to the value `application/json`.

`POST` is the http method.

`{"generalSearchInput":"Cheddar cheese"}` is the body of the request

The last line is the URL containing a placeholder for the API key.

A raw request would look like

```
POST /fdc/v1/search HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic REVNT19LRVk6
User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
Host: localhost
Accept: */*
Content-Type:application/json
Content-Length: 39

{"generalSearchInput":"Cheddar cheese"}
```

Comment: An HTTP request doesn't contain the full URL to the target machine. The first line of the request looks like this instead: `POST /fdc/v1/search HTTP/1.1`.